# 3D map visualization in Angular Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

### Preamble

I'm using [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) to indicate the location of different buildings across a campus. My initilization goes as follows:

```
 $scope.map = {
                    control: {},
                    center:
                    {
                        latitude: $scope.Item.Latitude,
                        longitude: $scope.Item.Longitude
                    },
                    zoom: 16,
                    options: {
                        streetViewControl: true,
                        maxZoom: 20,
                        minZoom: 8,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                    },
                    showTraffic: true,
                    showBicycling: true,
                    events: {
                        blacklist: ['drag', 'dragend', 'dragstart', 'center_changed']
                    }
              };
```

That works flawlessly for the following visualization:

[image]

However, I just noticed that there is 3D data available for the region, and I would like to have it renderized as such:

[image]

### Question

Is it possible, via Angular Google Maps, to configure my initialization in such a way as to show the map as indicated?

### Bonus Question

...would it be possible to programatically have the 'camera' spin around the marker (or the center)?

---

This is the Map link for the reference images:
https://www.google.com/maps/@40.9570608,-76.8816097,179a,20y,180h,41.69t/data=!3m1!1e3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can get with the Google Maps Javascript API is the [45° imagery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#45DegreeImagery).

Not like the `3D map visualization`, 45° imagery only has:
1) the 45° tile... 
2) 4 angels (0, 90, 180, 270)
3) only has SATELLITE mode. (Road names and other maps elements isn't shown even the maps is in HYBRID)
4) it is not available everywhere over the globe. (for example, 40.9570608,-76.8816097)

Look at this example for more information.
http://jsfiddle.net/u1qcf892/

Comment: I see, so is the 3D visualization restricted to GMaps itself or not available via the JS API yet?

Comment: I believe so, even the mobile version of the maps.google.com does not provide that functon.

Comment: I guess you're right - and thanks for the intermediate solution. I'll wait a couple years to implement this feature then. =)